# Windows Hosted SVN Repository Access on Networked Mac

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, wireless-networking, svn

I'm having some troubles with getting this working at the moment.

I have a Win7 physical PC and I have a MacBook Pro running OSX Mavericks and a Windows 8 in a Parallels VM.  I have both machines connected via my Wi-Fi router using DHCP.

On the physical Win7 box I have [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) installed which exposes my SVN repositories over https.  [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) is configured to use windows authentication and uses port 443.

When I boot up the VM and go into Windows 8 on the mac I can checkout my repositories without any problems at all using the https protocol.

I also have a number of shares setup on the Win 7 box which I can connect to using Finder>Go>Connect to Server whichout any problems, my Win7 authentication is stored in KeyChain and connects every time without any problems.

However I just cannot get SVN on OSX to perform a checkout over https.  Has anyone managed to get this configuration working?

The error I'm seeing at the moment in my Terminal window is:

```
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness I ended up getting this working by taking the path of least resistance!

Since I'm just a single developer working on my projects I have a fairly simple setup.  Rather than configure my Windows box with a static IP address I simply added a DHCP Reservation for the IP address so I can safely assume the IP address will be the same every time my main development box connects to the Wi-Fi router.

I then mapped this IP address to my server name using the hosts file on OSX and voila, all working and reliable.